# Java8 Lambda Deserialization - ClassCastException

Tags: java, serialization, lambda, java-8, classcastexception

`ClassCastException` is thrown by Java8 upon deserializing a lambda when following conditions are met:

- Parent class has a method, reference to which is used to automatically create a `Serializable` lambda
- There are several child classes that extend it and there are several usages of above method as a method reference, but with different child classes
- After method reference is consumed it is serialized and the deserialized
- All method references are used within the same capturing class

Tested on Oracle Java compiler and runtime versions 1.8.0_91.
Please find test code on how to reproduce:

```
import java.io.*;

/**
 * @author Max Myslyvtsev
 * @since 7/6/16
 */
public class LambdaSerializationTest implements Serializable {

    static abstract class AbstractConverter implements Serializable {
        String convert(String input) {
            return doConvert(input);
        }

        abstract String doConvert(String input);
    }

    static class ConverterA extends AbstractConverter {
        @Override
        String doConvert(String input) {
            return input + "_A";
        }
    }

    static class ConverterB extends AbstractConverter {
        @Override
        String doConvert(String input) {
            return input + "_B";
        }
    }

    static class ConverterC extends AbstractConverter {
        @Override
        String doConvert(String input) {
            return input + "_C";
        }
    }

    interface MyFunction<T, R> extends Serializable {
        R call(T var);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        ConverterA converterA = new ConverterA();
        ConverterB converterB = new ConverterB();
        ConverterC converterC = new ConverterC();
        giveFunction(converterA::convert);
        giveFunction(converterB::convert);
        giveFunction(converterC::convert);
    }

    private static void giveFunction(MyFunction<String, String> f) {
        f = serializeDeserialize(f);
        System.out.println(f.call("test"));
    }

    private static <T> T serializeDeserialize(T object) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(object);
            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T result = (T) ois.readObject();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

It gives following output:

```
1.8.0_91
test_A
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type
    at LambdaSerializationTest.serializeDeserialize(LambdaSerializationTest.java:68)
    at LambdaSerializationTest.giveFunction(LambdaSerializationTest.java:52)
    at LambdaSerializationTest.main(LambdaSerializationTest.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.throwMiscException(ObjectStreamClass.java:1582)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1154)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1817)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at LambdaSerializationTest.serializeDeserialize(LambdaSerializationTest.java:65)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.readResolve(SerializedLambda.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1148)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: LambdaSerializationTest$ConverterB cannot be cast to LambdaSerializationTest$ConverterA
    at LambdaSerializationTest.$deserializeLambda$(LambdaSerializationTest.java:7)
    ... 21 more
```

Upon decompiling this `$deserializeLambda$` method with CFR following code is revealed:

```
private static /* synthetic */ Object $deserializeLambda$(SerializedLambda lambda) {
    switch (lambda.getImplMethodName()) {
        case "convert": {
            if (lambda.getImplMethodKind() == 5 && lambda.getFunctionalInterfaceClass().equals("LambdaSerializationTest$MyFunction") && lambda.getFunctionalInterfaceMethodName().equals("call") && lambda.getFunctionalInterfaceMethodSignature().equals("(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;") && lambda.getImplClass().equals("LambdaSerializationTest$AbstractConverter") && lambda.getImplMethodSignature().equals("(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;")) {
                return (MyFunction<String, String>)LambdaMetafactory.altMetafactory(null, null, null, (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, convert(java.lang.String ), (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;)((ConverterA)((ConverterA)lambda.getCapturedArg(0)));
            }
            if (lambda.getImplMethodKind() == 5 && lambda.getFunctionalInterfaceClass().equals("LambdaSerializationTest$MyFunction") && lambda.getFunctionalInterfaceMethodName().equals("call") && lambda.getFunctionalInterfaceMethodSignature().equals("(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;") && lambda.getImplClass().equals("LambdaSerializationTest$AbstractConverter") && lambda.getImplMethodSignature().equals("(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;")) {
                return (MyFunction<String, String>)LambdaMetafactory.altMetafactory(null, null, null, (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, convert(java.lang.String ), (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;)((ConverterB)((ConverterB)lambda.getCapturedArg(0)));
            }
            if (lambda.getImplMethodKind() != 5 || !lambda.getFunctionalInterfaceClass().equals("LambdaSerializationTest$MyFunction") || !lambda.getFunctionalInterfaceMethodName().equals("call") || !lambda.getFunctionalInterfaceMethodSignature().equals("(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;") || !lambda.getImplClass().equals("LambdaSerializationTest$AbstractConverter") || !lambda.getImplMethodSignature().equals("(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;")) break;
            return (MyFunction<String, String>)LambdaMetafactory.altMetafactory(null, null, null, (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, convert(java.lang.String ), (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;)((ConverterC)((ConverterC)lambda.getCapturedArg(0)));
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid lambda deserialization");
}
```

So it appears that actual captured argument is not used to determine which exact lambda has to be deserialized. All 3 lambdas will satisfy 1st `if` condition and `ConverterA` will be assumed.

When debugging we can observe that in runtime `lambda.getCapturedArg(0)` is of a correct type (`ConverterB` when exception is thrown) and also it worth noting that cast is not needed since method to be invoked is present in base `AbstractConverter` class.

Is it expected behavior? If yes, what is recommended workaround?

Comment: On my PC it works like a charm with output:1.8.0_60
test_A
test_B
test_C

Comment: Could it be platform specific? I am using Mac OS.

Comment: I am also using Mac :)

Comment: Could you please try decompiling your `$deserializeLambda$` method with [CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/) like this:
`java -jar cfr_0_115.jar LambdaSerializationTest.class --removeboilerplate false --decodelambdas false`

Comment: If you suspect a bug, you should always include the exact compiler version, i.e. which jdk and/or whether you use a custom compiler like Eclipse.

Comment: Of course, this is a bug. I don’t think that the `$deserializeLambda$` method should test the types of captured values, but the compiler should not encode the fact that the method `convert` is inherited from `AbstractConverter`. Instead, it should encode exactly what you have written, i.e. references to `ConverterA::convert`, `ConverterB::convert`, and `ConverterC::convert`, just like it would for ordinary method invocations. If it did, the `implClass` comparison would differentiate the creation sites.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov: are you using Eclipse or any other IDE with its own compiler?

Comment: Yes I compiled it in Eclipse. But it is not using Own compiler it has the same compiler set that is in the command line.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov: Eclipse *has* its own compiler. I even don’t know of any option to tell Eclipse to use `javac` instead of its builtin compiler (besides using an external build tool like `ant`).

Comment: OK i will try from the console in an hour and let you know how IT goes.

Comment: @Holger: I would not expect the compiler to reference exact `ConverterX::convert` methods, because those methods do not actually exist (there is only `AbstractConverter::convert` method). So instead I would prefer the compiler to generate just a single `if` condition and cast to `AbstractConverter` inside of it.

Comment: These methods *do* exist, the fact that these `ConverterX` classes inherit the method rather than declaring or overriding it, is an implementation detail of the `ConverterX` classes which should *not* affect the code of the caller. Think about it: why should the decision of overriding the method in `ConverterX` (or not) change the code of the caller? That would imply that you have to recompile your applications for every new JRE release…

Comment: @Holger: agreed, I was just confused by the fact that `ConverterX` does not _declare_ `convert` method. But if you just invoke `ConverterA.convert()` directly, following bytecode will be generated `INVOKEVIRTUAL LambdaSerializationTest$ConverterA.convert` implying that `ConverterA` has a virtual method `convert` which proves your point.

Comment: So is there a resolution ?

Comment: I have sent a bug report to Oracle and they are currently evaluating it. I will post here in case of any updates.

Comment: That’s why I wrote “*just like it would for ordinary method invocations*”. I remember times, when Java 1.2 was really new, where the compiler *did* use the declaring class in invocations, leading to surprising behavior, e.g. a Java 1.1 compatible program, recompiled under 1.2 with `-target 1.1` still failed to run under 1.1 due to references to 1.2 specific classes it never referenced by itself. But that was almost twenty years ago…

Comment: Oracle has confirmed a bug, updated the post with details.

Comment: @Max Myslyvtsev: I turned your last update into an answer as I think, that’s more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle has confirmed that it is a bug and assigned a following Bug ID: `JDK-8161257`

It is now visible on the official tracker: [JDK-8161257](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8161257)